# Making a histogram from Json data

Tags: python, json, histogram

I have data in JSON format that looks something like this

```json
{
   "ts": 1393631983,
   "visitor_uuid": "ade7e1f63bc83c66",
   "visitor_source": "external",
   "visitor_device": "browser",
   "visitor_useragent": "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16",
   "visitor_ip": "b5af0ba608ab307c",
   "visitor_country": "BR",
   "visitor_referrer": "53c643c16e8253e7",
   "env_type": "reader",
   "env_doc_id": "140222143932-91796b01f94327ee809bd759fd0f6c76",
   "event_type": "pagereadtime",
   "event_readtime": 1010,
   "subject_type": "doc",
   "subject_doc_id": "140222143932-91796b01f94327ee809bd759fd0f6c76",
   "subject_page": 3
} {
    "ts": 1393631983,
    "visitor_uuid": "232eeca785873d35",
    "visitor_source": "internal",
    "visitor_device": "browser",
    "visitor_useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36",
    "visitor_ip": "fcf9c67037f993f0",
    "visitor_country": "MX",
    "visitor_referrer": "63765fcd2ff864fd",
    "env_type": "stream",
    "env_ranking": 10,
    "env_build": "1.7.118-b946",
    "env_name": "explore",
    "env_component": "editors_picks",
    "event_type": "impression",
    "subject_type": "doc",
    "subject_doc_id": "100713205147-2ee05a98f1794324952eea5ca678c026",
    "subject_page": 1
}
```

My task requires me to  find subject_doc_id that matches an input from user and then display a histogram showing the countries in which that document has been viewed.

I have been able to read through the data that with my code and I am also familiar with how to plot a histogram but I need help on how to count the countries and display that in the histogram.

For example here in the data above  "visitor_country":"MX" and "visitor_country":"BR" exist so I want the count of each country.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json file isn't correct json file.
You need to add a "[" at the start and "]" at the end of a file and separate each "{}" section by comma.
Here is an example:

Data.json

```json
[
    {
   "ts": 1393631983,
   "visitor_uuid": "ade7e1f63bc83c66",
   "visitor_source": "external",
   "visitor_device": "browser",
   "visitor_useragent": "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16",
   "visitor_ip": "b5af0ba608ab307c",
   "visitor_country": "BR",
   "visitor_referrer": "53c643c16e8253e7",
   "env_type": "reader",
   "env_doc_id": "140222143932-91796b01f94327ee809bd759fd0f6c76",
   "event_type": "pagereadtime",
   "event_readtime": 1010,
   "subject_type": "doc",
   "subject_doc_id": "140222143932-91796b01f94327ee809bd759fd0f6c76",
   "subject_page": 3
}, {
    "ts": 1393631983,
    "visitor_uuid": "232eeca785873d35",
    "visitor_source": "internal",
    "visitor_device": "browser",
    "visitor_useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36",
    "visitor_ip": "fcf9c67037f993f0",
    "visitor_country": "MX",
    "visitor_referrer": "63765fcd2ff864fd",
    "env_type": "stream",
    "env_ranking": 10,
    "env_build": "1.7.118-b946",
    "env_name": "explore",
    "env_component": "editors_picks",
    "event_type": "impression",
    "subject_type": "doc",
    "subject_doc_id": "100713205147-2ee05a98f1794324952eea5ca678c026",
    "subject_page": 1
}, {
    "ts": 1393631983,
    "visitor_uuid": "232eeca785873d35",
    "visitor_source": "internal",
    "visitor_device": "browser",
    "visitor_useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36",
    "visitor_ip": "fcf9c67037f993f0",
    "visitor_country": "PL",
    "visitor_referrer": "63765fcd2ff864fd",
    "env_type": "stream",
    "env_ranking": 10,
    "env_build": "1.7.118-b946",
    "env_name": "explore",
    "env_component": "editors_picks",
    "event_type": "impression",
    "subject_type": "doc",
    "subject_doc_id": "100713205147-2ee05a98f1794324952eea5ca678c026",
    "subject_page": 1
}
, {
    "ts": 1393631983,
    "visitor_uuid": "232eeca785873d35",
    "visitor_source": "internal",
    "visitor_device": "browser",
    "visitor_useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36",
    "visitor_ip": "fcf9c67037f993f0",
    "visitor_country": "PL",
    "visitor_referrer": "63765fcd2ff864fd",
    "env_type": "stream",
    "env_ranking": 10,
    "env_build": "1.7.118-b946",
    "env_name": "explore",
    "env_component": "editors_picks",
    "event_type": "impression",
    "subject_type": "doc",
    "subject_doc_id": "100713205147-2ee05a98f1794324952eea5ca678c026",
    "subject_page": 1
}
]
```

After that For each element in the data.json file i'm checking if it is a match to our input subject_doc_id. If we got a match i'm appending it to a list of matches, so we can collect the data for our histogram. After that i want to get a number of bins based on the number of unique countries to do so i'm creating a unique list of countries and then i'm checking it's length.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

with open("data.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

#Here is the subject id i'm using for the data presentation
#100713205147-2ee05a98f1794324952eea5ca678c026
subject_id = input("subject_doc_id: ")
visitors = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if subject_id == data[i]["subject_doc_id"]:
        print("got a match from {}".format(data[i]["visitor_country"]))
        visitors.append(data[i]["visitor_country"])
countries = []
for i in visitors:
    if i not in countries:
        countries.append(i)
try:
    plt.hist(visitors, bins = len(countries))
    plt.show()
except ValueError:
    print("No matches for given subject_doc_id")
```

If you want to sort it by continents you need to first know which country belongs to which continent. My example:

```
continents = {
    "europe": ["PL, GER"],
    "south_america": ["BR"],
    "north_america": ["MX"]
}
```

I'm python newbie so i don't know any fancy techniques to sort the previous lists except for loops.

```py
continent_data = []
for continent in continents:
    for visitor_country in visitors:
        for country in continents[continent]:
            if visitor_country in country:
                continent_data.append(continent)
print(continent_data)
```

After that you can just use the previous code to sort it into unique values for bins and create a histogram based on the example above

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Very much appreciated. Do you have any idea as to what I could do if I wanted to group the countries by continent and then display it in another histogram? Thanks again.

Comment: @user17534067 That sounds like a new question to be asked. Feel free to ask another question as comments are meant for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I had to slightly modify your file contents to make it valid JSON, and then saved it as 'jsonExample.json' in my working directory.

After modification, the json data took this form:

```
{
"visitor1": {[your data]}
"visotor2": {[your data]}
}
```

Then with the json library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) you can just make a list with the country of each visitor and count how many times each one appears:

```py
import json

with open("jsonExample.json", 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
visitors = json.loads(contents)

countryList = []
for v in visitors.keys():
    if visitors[v]['subject_doc_id'] == "desired_subject_doc_id":
        countryList.append(visitors[v]['visitor_country'])

for country in set(countryList):
    print(f"Country {country} appears {countryList.count(country)} times")
```

The `if visitors[v]['subject_doc_id']` statement checks if the `subject_doc_id` matches a specified value, just replace the RHS with the id required.

Comment: What was the modification?

Comment: what if I wanted count only for the countries for a specific document id (subject_doc_id) which is an input by the user.

Comment: Modified to show how that's done.  If you only want a single id this will be fine, but it can be stored in a variable if you want it to be easily modifiable.